# Updating empty cells with filled cells values in duplicate records without unique key

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table `tblPhone` which contains duplicate records. E.g.

```
Group    First_Name    Middle_Name    Last_Name    Class    ...    Note    ...Other_Columns
-----    ----------    -----------    ---------    -----    ...    ----    ...-------------
Avo      FirstName     MiddleName     LastName     246      ...    NULL    ...Other_Columns
Avo      FirstName     MiddleName     LastName     215      ...    Valu    ...Other_Columns
```

As you are seeing above sample table have two duplicate records without uniquely identified KEY.

1. Question 1 is: How I can uniquely identify each duplicate record in table?
2. See the `Note` column which has `NULL` value in first row and `Valu` some values in second row. Question 2 is: How I can update the value from filled cell `Valu` into empty/NULL cell?
3. Question 3 is: How I can take and update the lowest number value in each cell in `Class` column?

The UPDATE query that I tried to write is below but confused in CASE ELSE clauses:

```
UPDATE tblPhone
   SET [Note] = CASE WHEN [Note] = '' THEN [Note] = ???
WHERE Last_Name = 'LastName'
  AND First_Name = 'FirstName';
```

I have also created sample table schema here in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/840cb0/1).

Database is created in SQL Server 2017.

Comment: Are Group, First_Name, Last_Name, Class, and Suffix Nullable?  I didn't see that on the SQL Fiddle, but worth asking; I'm thinking composite key may help here, and may answer all three of your questions.  I think.

Comment: I'm going to assume they are; maybe make them not nullable, and build composite key from there?

Comment: No these two are not null-able but how I can apply composite KEY on same records ??

Comment: I suggested 4 columns, not two, based on your SQL Fiddle.  FIrst/Last Name, though not nullable, wouldn't be enough. I also suggested Class and Suffix.  HOWEVER, I'm a bit confused between your data listed as part of your post compared to the SQL Fiddle.  Is Class and Suffix not unique either?  Class looks unique on the post, not in the SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
UPDATE p1
    SET p1.[Note] = (
        SELECT TOP(1) [Note]
        FROM tblPhone p2 
        WHERE p2.[Note] IS NOT NULL 
            AND p2.First_Name = p1.First_Name
            AND p2.Last_Name = p1.Last_Name
        )
FROM tblPhone p1
WHERE p1.[Note] IS NULL;
```

Comment: I have [tested](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ab8ea/1) your solution but `Note` value is not updating...

Comment: It will not work if there are no notes for that first/last user, but otherwise it should

Comment: Thanks for helping! I've figured out it.